# What is a good solution for notification Tab in a mobile app

Tags: react-native, mobile, notifications

I am working on a mobile app, And i am wondering whats the best solution design for notifications tab - if we click on the notification tab, it shows all the recent notifications.

Any thoughts, how its stored in the backend and DB design, any best practices etc?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've made both the backend and respective mobile app part . For front end part its easy, you can either implemnt in a bottomTabNavigator where on click of that tab , it opens up a page and it calls the API to fetch all the notifications. And on PullToRefresh in the FlatList you can refresh the list of notitfications.

For backend there are 2 ways, either you store in a separate table/docuemnt for notifications and link with the users table. or store in the same collection of users.

Hope it helps. Feel free for doubts

Comment: my app has notifications linked to two users. Think of facebook, where one notification is generated because it has affected two users.

I think storing in a seperate table would be better approach. and then link it to relevant users. 
But if i go down this approach, wont there be performance issue. I mean with data read. How did you manage the performance?